# Magento cart link error

Tags: php, jquery, magento

I have the following links in my header:

- Account
- Wishlist
- Search
- Cart

They're all working properly, except for the cart link. Whenever the link is pressed, the console shows the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://myshop.com/checkout/cart/
```

The error refers to a Sizzle error function in a jQuery 1.10.2 script, I've looked through the script but there are multiple Sizzle scripts.

The link is called as followed in minicart.phtml:

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart')?>" class="skip-link skip-cart <?php if($_cartQty <= 0): ?> no-count<?php endif; ?>">
```

Does anybody have any ideas what may cause this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the class name "skip-link". If you need to redirect to the cart page, you remove this class name from the  tag and it will work. "skip-link" is used to show the content near to that link instead of redirecting to other page. If we use "skip-link", then the href attribute will have some identifier value like "#header-top"(it will be id of some hidden div or span) or something like that. That's why the js error happens, because it is trying to parse the href parameter as an element's id which is not in right syntax in this case.

Comment: Why this has been marked as the correct answer is beyond me because it doesn't resolve the original question, it actually removes the default behaviour that said classes are required for (popup of minicart when link is clicked). You can see the actual answer that will help [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/88697/798).

Comment: Amazing, Thanks :) ... Vote Up :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. However, I found that it was a caching issue after upgrading from Magento CE 1.9.0 to 1.9.1. The wrong app.js file was being used.

I had to clear all the Magento cache, browser cache and CDN (CloudFlare) cache to get it to work.

Comment: This is more like the correct answer than the one that is marked as the correct answer - it ties in with my answer on this [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/88697/798).